# accepts_nested_attributes_for is not filling the id of the nested items in a Rails 3.2 app using bootstrap and simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form

I have updated this question to reflect the input of those who made suggestions.

In a Rails 3.2 app with bootstrap and simple form I have the following in the invoice model:

```
has_many :line_items
accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_items
attr_accessible :user_id, :project_name, :date1, :date2, :date3, :paid, :memo, :line_items_attributes
```

In the line_item model:

```
belongs_to :invoice
# validates_presence_of :invoice_id (COMMENTED THESE OUT to generate a clearer error)
# validates_uniqueness_of :invoice_id
```

In my invoice controller I have:

```
  def new
     @users = User.find(:all, :order => "username asc")

     @line_items = [] # got "undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass" until defined as array
     Product.find(:all, :order => "position asc").each do |p|
        @line_items << LineItem.new(:product_id => p.id, :cost => p.unit_cost, :name => p.name, :description => p.description, :position => p.position, :quantity => 0)
     end

     @invoice = Invoice.new(:line_items_attributes => @line_items) # PRODUCING ERROR
  end
```

In my form I have the following:

```
<%= simple_form_for @invoice do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :user_id, :collection => @users.map(&:username) %>
    <%= f.input :project_name %>
    <%= f.input :date1, :as => :date, :order => [:month, :day, :year], :label => "3rd Invoice" %>

    <%= f.simple_fields_for :line_items do |li_fields| %>
        <%= li_fields.input :name %>
        <%= li_fields.input :quantity %>
        <%= li_fields.input :unit_cost %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.button :submit, "Save", :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Again in my controller:

```
  def create
    @invoice = Invoice.new(params[:invoice])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @invoice.save
         ...
      else
         ...
      end
    end
  end
```

Error message:

```
undefined method `with_indifferent_access' for #<LineItem:0x007ffc9ebc0730>
```

p @line_items yields:

```
[#<LineItem id: nil, invoice_id: nil, product_id: 5, cost: #<BigDecimal:7ffc9e45d330,'0.69E2',9(18)>, name: "Account", description: "Account", quantity: 0, position: 2, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, 
 #<LineItem id: nil, invoice_id: nil, product_id: 12, cost: #<BigDecimal:7ffc9e45c9f8,'0.3E3',9(18)>, name: "Consultant Training", description: "Consultant Training", quantity: 0, position: 12, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JasonSwett, come and git it!

Comment: Could you post the params as they come into the controller so that we can see that nothing funny has happened?

Comment: it should be `<%= f.simple_fields_for "line_items[#{index}]", line_item do |li_fields| %>`

Comment: @Jesper, params posted. Thanks.

Comment: what about the other side of the association, do you have `belongs_to :invoice`?

Comment: @SybariteManoj, yes, it is in the model. Updated the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in your form set up.  You have `@invoice.line_items.each_with_index do |line_item, index|` before your f.simple_fields_for and you don't need it. Instead you should have...

```
<%= simple_form_for(@invoice) do |f| %>
    ...some inputs    
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :line_items do |li_fields| %>
        ...more inputs
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Then, in your invoice model you want to make sure you make `line_items_attributes` attr_accessible.

Comment: Hey, rocket scientist. Thanks for the help. It didn't work though. Updated the question.

Comment: I would also look at this line `@invoice.line_items << LineItem.new(...attributes...)`.  This may be causing a problem because you are populating the line_items before the parent is saved.  When I have pre populated child objects for a new parent in the past I have used something like this `line_items_attributes = #array of new line items` and then `@invoice = Invoice.new(:line_items => line_items_attributes)`

Comment: Ugh... tried numerous variations of the above. "And I think its gonna be a long, long time..."

Comment: Will post the solution after I get it cleaned up

Comment: Yay! Im glad you figured it out :) Nothing beats getting a break through after you have spent hours debugging!